# How can I call my Calculator to popup on click, at my website with a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, css, function

**My Index** (PHP)
On `<div class="button">` I need my onclick.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
        
<div class="form">
<input type="number">

    <div class="button"> **Here I need the onclick popup call calculator**
    
       <img src="https://www.iconarchive.com/download/i58919/wwalczyszyn/android-style-honeycomb/Calculator.ico"></img>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**My Calculator is a php file called** *calculator.php* **followed by** *calculator.css* **and** *script.js*

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to include your calculator.php in your index.php and to only show / hide the "calculator" element ?

Comment: I want to place the button within a function and call it several times in my website.

Comment: No problem, the calculator could be a child of the `<body>`, any button would open the same calculator

Comment: Actually I want a function to work on a button onclick. Think it like a plug-in, wherever I place the button (with a function ();), when you press on it the calculator pop-up.

Comment: I understood, my point is you don't need to load your calculator on the click. It can be allready hidden (`display: none`) in the page and display whenever the user click on a button. Your function will do something like `document.getElementById('calculator').style.display = 'block'`